Out of RAM while tokenize a 12GB xml with SpaCy
I'm trying to tokenize a 12GB of text in xml. The file contains only "content words" with no stopwords. I am trying to implement a function in order to tokenize by chunks of text and clean the RAM. (I have a core i7 and 32GB of RAM)
I have tried the following without success;
from spacy.util import minibatch
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")
nlp.disable_pipes('tok2vec', 'morphologizer', 'parser', 'senter', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner')

def tokenizer(corpus_file):
    all_tokens = []

    with open(corpus_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for batch in minibatch(file, size=100):
            docs = nlp.pipe(batch)
            for doc in docs:
                tokens = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_space]
                all_tokens.extend(tokens)
    return all_tokens


An official solution will come with upcoming release version 4. See https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/11295#event-7177460322 .
You must deal with your trick, for example, break down it to smaller parts.
